# Filtering Soundcloud results by tags

Tags: javascript, tags, filtering, soundcloud

I'm working with this thing: http://grouprecorder.soundcloudlabs.com – a recording Widget from Soundcloud. I got it to work as it's supposed to, recording and uploading tracks to a specified group, as well as listing that group's tracks. On top of that, however, I wanted to add a simple function, making an experimental audio commentary system on a blog.

In order to do that I must differentiate between comments made on different posts. I managed to do so, passing a WordPress post's ID to the widget's iFrame, and carry that on as a SoundCloud track tag. It uploads precisely as it should to.

Then, however, once I want to filter the tracks to be listed in the widget, to only show ones with the correct tag, I'm a little lost.

This is the original bit of code:

`return SC.get(GR.groupUrl + "/tracks", {
    limit: 5,
},`

Simple enough. I have tried adding all variations of tags, taglist, tag_list, that seem remotely possible, as in:

`return SC.get(GR.groupUrl + "/tracks", {
    limit: 5,
    tags: postIDtag
},`

– *postIDtag* being my otherwise very well functioning postID variable.

And yet the widget keeps posting the whole list of the group's tracks, unfiltered.

Others seem to have had related problems in the past. It seems to be impossible to filter by user and tags at the same time. Perhaps the same goes for groups. If so using the tags alone would be fine by me, as I can make them specific enough to exclude any tracks outside the group. But I'm a novice at javascript, so I'm unsure if it's me or them, that's at fault here. Can anyone help me out, or am I trying something not supported in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a lot of work with the Soundcloud API in the past and found that the API itself for rendering specific data on a page is pretty ... awful.

What I do to avoid these issues is work with the tracks array itself rather than working with the array via the soundcloud API. Here's an example:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.soundcloud.com/groups/57713/tracks.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID", function(data) {
    var tracks = $.map(data, function(track) {
        return {
            track: track.title,
            stream: track.stream_url + '?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
            tags: track.tag_list
        };
    });
    console.log(tracks);
});
```

*Updated: 27.05.2014*

What you'll now see in your console are two separate logs:

- `console.log(data)` shows the returned objects from soundcloud
- `console.log(this.tracks)` shows the objects from soundcloud in their manipulated form.

Comment: Thank you. You mean it is fully possible to bypass the API and query the database directly? That means I have a steeper learning curve ahead than I expected, but should eventually resolve the issue.

Comment: I get an error message as I try to implement the solution:

GET  … 404 (Not Found) 

I am positive the ID is correct and the same as I initialize with.

Comment: Got through. Had to erase 'api' from the beginning of the URL-example you provided. That leaves me with a whole different problem: 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myurl.com' is therefore not allowed access.' I go on in the good faith that this backdoor access is, nonetheless, somehow eventually open.

Comment: I think you need to the API in the link or you won't get the correct returned but that error happens when you request data from other sites/services and you need to use JSONP instead of JSON. Can you tell me the error you get when you use the link with API in it?

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. I am not allowed to 1-up answers yet, but I most certainly would already. In any case: When I write: _jQuery.getJSON("http://api.soundcloud.com/groups/[mygroup]/tracks.json?client_id=[my-id]", function(data) {
_ I get: _GET http://api.soundcloud.com/groups/simsvari/tracks.json?client_id=5b16821f8720592f30a3b37700b3bbc9 404 (Not Found) _. Changing JSON to JSONP, as such, is not recognized and gets an 'undefined' error. I am on my way to find out how to load that library and go on – but if you have any tips at this stage, I would be most grateful.

Comment: Last problem solved: 1. I was using my group's name, and not the ID number. Changed that. 2. I added &callback=myurl/callback.html to the request. I'm in, or so it seems – the script loads without errors, but I am yet to see the log appear. I will keep this thread open until the whole problem is solved. Thank you so much, once more – and obviously I wouldn't say no to further tips.

Comment: @Harukimar could you expand a little more on "I am yet to see the log appear?"

Comment: When the console ceased giving me error messages, it just gave me nothing. No log.

Comment: I am amazed! Thank you.

Comment: @Harukimar if you could +1 it too that'd be great! :D

Comment: I'm at 13 points myself and not allowed to yet. Will do at the first opportunity.